# Selenium how to get cell value in a grid based on grid coordinates

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, html-table

HTML

```html
<div id="model" class="mobile handsontable htRowHeaders htColumnHeaders" style="height: 100%; overflow: hidden;" data-originalstyle="height: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
  <div class="ht_master handsontable"><div class="wtHolder" style="position: relative; height: 380px; width: 1468px;">
  <div class="wtHider" style="width: 2550px; height: 2109px;">
    <div class="wtSpreader" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
      <table class="htCore">
        <colgroup>
          <col class="rowHeader" style="width: 50px;">
          <col style="width: 400px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
        </colgroup>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="">
              <div class="relative">
                <span class="colHeader cornerHeader">&nbsp;</span>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th class=""> 
              <div class="relative">
                <span class="colHeader">Division, Base Alternative</span>
              </div>
             </th>
            <th class="">
              <div class="relative">
                <span class="colHeader">2015 (M)</span>
              </div>
             </th>
            <th class="">
              <div class="relative">
                <span class="colHeader">2016 (N)</span>
              </div>
             </th>
            <th class="">
              <div class="relative">
                <span class="colHeader">2017 (O)</span>
              </div>
             </th>
            <th class="">
              <div class="relative">
                <span class="colHeader">2018 (P)</span>
              </div>
             </th>
            <th class="">
              <div class="relative">
                <span class="colHeader">2019 (Q)</span>
              </div>
            </th>
           </tr>
          <thead>
            <tr>                                                                                                     <th class="" style="height: 17px;">
                <div class="relative">
                  <span class="rowHeader">1</span>
                </div>
                </th>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap"></td>
              <td class="afterHiddenColumn htDimmed htNoWrap"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap"></td>
            <tr>
              <th class="" style="height: 17px;">
                <div class="relative">
                  <span class="rowHeader">2</span>
                </div>
               </th>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(194, 218, 254); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: left;"></td>
              <td class="afterHiddenColumn htDimmed htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;"></td>
            </tr>
           <tr>
            <th class="" style="height: 17px;">
              <div class="relative">
                <span class="rowHeader">3</span>
              </div>
             </th>
            <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(194, 218, 254); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: left;">Model period</td>
            <td class="afterHiddenColumn htRight htNumeric htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 128); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
            <td class="htRight htNumeric htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 128); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
            <td class="htRight htNumeric htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 128); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
            <td class="htRight htNumeric htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 128); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
            <td class="htRight htNumeric htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 128); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
            <td class="htRight htNumeric htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 128); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
            <td class="htRight htNumeric htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 128); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
            <td class="htRight htNumeric htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 128); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
          </tr>         
        <tr>
          <th class="" style="height: 17px;">
            <div class="relative">
              <span class="rowHeader">7</span>
            </div>
           </th>
          <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(194, 218, 254); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: left;">Pulp sales, pulp mill, MUSD</td>
          <td class="afterHiddenColumn htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
          <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
          <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">597</td>
          <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">572</td>
          <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">648</td>
          <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">35</td>
          <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">326</td>
          <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">326</td>
        </tr>
       <tr>
        <th class="" style="height: 17px;">
          <div class="relative">
            <span class="rowHeader">8</span>
          </div>
         </th>
        <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(194, 218, 254); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: left;">Pulp sales, paper mill, MUSD</td>
        <td class="afterHiddenColumn htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
       </tr>
      </thead>
```

I want to get a specific cell in this grid shown below
based on the row number on the left side and the column names on the top.

> [image]
>
> Let say I want to get the cell with the value `597`

> Instead of finding it with the value/text or index,
> I want to get the cell based on the `row number` & `column name`

Something like this

> find the cell that has the row number of 7 and column name of 2017 (O)

Expected Output

```
597
```

> **If the row or column is selected
>
> they get a class named `ht__highlight`**

> **If the cell is selected
>
> it gets a class named `htNoWrap current highlight`**

I have searched for 2 days now,
and I can't find any answers or
examples of this situation

*This is quite hard to explain so I apologize for the messy explanation*

*Thanks in Advance!!!!*

Comment: You complicate everything. Just add html code for the page.

Comment: I'll add how a locator should look like, but without full HTML it is hard to tell for sure

Answer (score 1):

The approach should look like this:

```
rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".rowHeader") 
for row in rows:
    row_2015 = row.find_element_by_css_selector(".colHeader:nth-of-type(1)").text
    row_2016 = row.find_element_by_css_selector(".colHeader:nth-of-type(2)").text
```

1. You get all rows by finding a unique row locator (for example, for 15 rows - 15 results)
2. You loop through table rows and get individual cells text.

In other words, you css selector should look like this:

```
expected_text = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".rowHeader:nth-of-type(1)>.colHeader:nth-of-type(1)").text
```

Without full HTML page it's hard to say for sure.

**Try 2:**

With the conditions you specified use the following `xpath`:

```
//span[contains(text(),'2017 (O)')]/../../../../../thead[2]/tr[4]/td[4]
```

It directly locates cell with tha value 597 by column name.
First it finds the column name, then goes few level up in order to obtain values from the second `thead`.

Try changing `tr[4]/td[4]` part and you will get any value from the table by xpath.

Comment: What should I have instead of "nth-of-type"? I get UnableToLocateElement error

Comment: I have updated my question. Please take a look!

Comment: Does the question remain the same, you want to take cell with value 597? Or there are some other conditions?

Comment: Yes, still cell with value 597 but locating it based on the row number and column name coordinates. @vitaliis

Comment: Please check the answer and let me know if it works

Comment: It did not work, but I think I solved it now actually. But thanks for the help!!

Comment: What is your final locator? Interesting why mine did not work

Comment: `//tr[{}]//td[count(//table[@class='htCore']//th[contains(., '{}')]//preceding-sibling::th`